# Antimatter asymmetry in the proton

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, antimatter, quarks, protons

What are the prevailing models of why the proton has an excess of antimatter down quarks? If there are no prevailing models what types of conditions in the nucleus would cause it? Is this topic waiting for further results to verify it?
https://news.umich.edu/study-finds-unexpected-antimatter-asymmetry-in-the-proton/

Answer (score 0):

One can find the paper in [the arxiv,](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.04024)

From the abstract:

> An essential feature of this force, as described by quantum chromodynamics, is its ability to create matter-antimatter quark pairs inside the proton that exist only for a very short time. Their fleeting existence makes the antimatter quarks within protons difficult to study, but their existence is discernible in reactions where a matter-antimatter quark pair annihilates. In this picture of quark-antiquark creation by the strong force, the probability distributions as a function of momentum for the presence of up and down antimatter quarks should be nearly identical, since their masses are quite similar and small compared to the mass of the proton. In the present manuscript, we show evidence from muon pair production measurements that these distributions are significantly different, with more abundant down antimatter quarks than up antimatter quarks over a wide range of momentum. These results revive interest in several proposed mechanisms as the origin of this antimatter asymmetry in the proton that had been disfavored by the previous results and point to the future measurements that can distinguish between these mechanisms.

The experiment is focused on the behavior of the interactions with antiquarks, from the virtual **pairs** that are modeled to exist within a proton with Quantum Field Theory. This image from prof [Matt Strassler](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/) gives an intuition:

[image: proton]

This topic needs further theoretical and phenomenological research, to be resolved within the existing models of the nucleus.

The reason it focuses on detecting antiquarks from the pairs is so that the distributions do not get contaminated from the momentum  distribution of the valence quarks.

Comment: Is it wrong to say 1000 hypothesis papers were written about the 750Gev dilepton excess and nothing has been fielded regarding this anomaly?

Comment: Yes, because this paper is from 2021 may, whereas the anomaly you speak of is from 2015. You have to wait six years to count the responsive papers in order to compare.